# where does libreoffice snap installation install python interpreter?

Tags: python, libreoffice, snap

I have recently swiched to a Libreoffice installed by snap on Ubuntu 20.4 LTS.

I can not find where this snap installations has put the python interpreter embedded in Libreoffice.

In the "regular" debian packages based installations, this program was located in `/opt/libreofficev.v/program/python.bin`

Purpose is to be able to reference that as the interpreter in a pycharm when I develop Libreoffice python macro.

Comment: IT will probably be found in the file system of the mounted libreoffice snap.

Comment: Also posted at https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/310288/where-does-libreoffice-snap-installation-install-python-interpreter/.

Comment: @JimK :  Yes, I posted the question on the 2 forums, thought it might not be the same audience

Comment: @vanadium : snap moutns libreoffice under /snap/libreoffice and there is nothing in the treestructure like the previous python.bin that I can find in the dpkg installed libreoffice versions...

Comment: Can't check because I removed snap, but perhaps in a different "library" snap?

Comment: Regarding the cross post, yes, this is a good question to post in both places. However in my opinion (not sure if there is complete agreement about this on StackExchange or not), you should have provided the links. That way people don't waste time answering a question that was already answered, and also you are likely to get more accurate responses because more information is usually available from comments or answers on the other site.

Answer (score 0):

A snap package has access only to its own files (unless it uses the `classic` confinement and LibreOffice does not use it). These files are in `/snap/libreoffice/current/`.

The Python interpreter is in `/snap/libreoffice/current/gnome-platform/usr/bin/python3`.

Let's run it!

```
$ /snap/libreoffice/current/gnome-platform/usr/bin/python3
bash: /snap/libreoffice/current/gnome-platform/usr/bin/python3: No such file or directory
$ ls -l /snap/libreoffice/current/gnome-platform/usr/bin/python3
ls: cannot access '/snap/libreoffice/current/gnome-platform/usr/bin/python3': No such file or directory
$
```

What gives? What's wrong? Well, you need to enter that namespace in order to be able to run executables. You do that with the following.

```
$ snap run --shell libreoffice
To run a command as administrator (user "root"), use "sudo <command>".
See "man sudo_root" for details.

$ cd /snap/libreoffice/current/gnome-platform/usr/bin/
$ ./python3
Python 3.6.9 (default, Jul 17 2020, 12:50:27) 
[GCC 8.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

LibreOffice's Python interpreter comes from the shared GNOME snap package, most likely `gnome-3-38-2004`.

However, the pyCharm snap package uses the `classic` confinement which means it can and does use the Python that has been installed on your system.